Does this identity exist? $1=(-1)!+(-2)!$
Does this identity exist?
$$
1 = \left(-1\right)! + \left(-2\right)!
$$
where "$!$" is the factorial function.
Because
$$
n! - \left(n - 1\right)! = \left(n - 2\right)! \quad\implies\quad
n\left(n - 1\right)\left(n - 2\right)!
- \left(n - 1\right)\left(n - 2\right)! = \left(n - 2\right)!
$$
meaning that $\left(n - 1\right)^{2} = 1$, giving the two solutions $n = 2$ or $n = 0$.

Do you have a question?  You know that, say, $3!-2!=6-2=4\neq 1!$, right?

yeah, the only solutions are n=2 and n=0.

The only solutions to what?    Your first equation, $n!-(n-1)! =(n-2)! $, is simply wrong.

How so? I'm referencing $1=(-1)!+(-2)!$ as the identity; sorry if that's not clear.

@LucienJaccon Are you solving $n!-(n-1)!=(n-2)!$ for $n$? Only $n=2$ is the solution. The factorial or gamma function of negative integers is undefined to avoid division by $0$.

The equation $(n-1)^2x=x$ does not imply $(n-1)^2=1$, other solutions being $x=0$ and $x=\pm\infty$.

I suggest:  edit you post for clarity.  It's really not clear what you are assuming nor what you want to prove.  The standard factorial is only defined for non-negative integers, there are ways to extend it but you can't just assume that it all works out smoothly.  State your assumptions clearly and work from there.

You wrote "Because $n!-(n-1)!=(n-2)!$..." but that equation is nonsense.  It simply isn't true.  Maybe you meant something else, but what you wrote is wrong.

there is an 'implies' after the 'because.' Hope that helps. However, as user1411 productively pointed out (and actually helped), the next line of reasoning is false.

$\displaystyle \LARGE !: \mathbb{C}\setminus\left{-1, -2, -3,\ldots\right} \to \mathbb{C}$

No idea what you are saying.  What you wrote in your post is nonsense.  Perhaps you meant something that wasn't nonsense, but whatever that was didn't make it into your question. This question ought to be closed.

@FelixMarin $\displaystyle \LARGE \Gamma: \mathbb{C}\setminus\left{0, -1, -2, -3,\ldots\right} \to \mathbb{C}$.
$\displaystyle \LARGE !: \mathbb{Z}\geq\to \mathbb{Z}>$.

@PustamRaut $0$ k. It’s a semantic idea. Thanks.

The factorial function is defined for non-negative integers. One way to extend the domain of the factorial or gamma function to negative numbers is by repeatedly applying the recurrence formula: $n!=n(n-1)!$ or $\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)$.
$$n!=\dfrac{(n+r+1)!}{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+r+1)}$$
choosing $r$ such that $(n+r+1)$ is not negative. The product in the denominator is zero when $n$ equals any of the integers $-1,-2, -3,\ldots$. Thus, the factorial function must be undefined at those points to avoid division by zero. The gamma function is a meromorphic function with simple poles (the integral definition diverges) at the non-positive integers.
Now, $(-1)!=\infty,\ (-2)!=-\infty$. So, $(-1)!+(-2)!=\infty-\infty\neq1$. $(\infty-\infty)$ is a well-known indeterminate form. Thus, $\mathbf{1=(-1)!+(-2)!}$ is not true.
Only $n=2$ satisfies the given equation $n!-(n-1)!=(n-2)!$, i.e., $2!=1!+0!$ is true. That extra $n=0$ arises due to the cancellation of the common factor $(n-2)!=-\infty$. Cancelling terms which become $0$ or $\infty$ (or subtracting $\infty$) leads to invalid or incorrect results due to indeterminate forms $0/0,\ \infty/\infty$, and $\infty-\infty$.
I hope this clarifies.

The factorial function is not defined on negative numbers.  The referenced "identity" is, therefore, not true.  It's like asking if 1/0 can be involved in any identity.  Since division by zero causes (1/0) to not be defined, no valid mathematical statement can be made with that term (unless, within the specific context, you define it).

i don't know if this makes sense or not, but could you still argue that as you approach the undefined values, the equality holds true?

@LucienJaccon no you can't argue that. They're undefined so what you've written is entirely meaningless. Putting symbols down doesn't give them meaning, you have to define them.
